# angular2 version 4.0.1 - Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: angular

This worked in angular2... 2.x

```
imports: [
....
ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'))
]
```

In an angular2 4.0.1

```
Failed to compile.

/Users/angular2isstupid/Documents/frontend/ang4test/src/app/app.module.ts (44,25): Cannot find name 'require'.
```

How do I deal with these changes?

Comment: dudes at this repo https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts no longer support angular2 so don't waste your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
declare var require: any;
```

to your src/typings.d.ts file.